# T-SQL unexpected behavior in isnull function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When i run this query i expect the result will be 'false'

```
IF isnull(0,'') = '' 
      select 'true' 

else 
     select 'false'
```

But sql Server tells me 'true', why?

Comment: Because isnull(0,'') returns the integer 0, and if you check your second operand also as integer : select cast('' as integer), it also returns 0. You shouldn't use different types, this ends with this kind of conversion issues.

Comment: Why do you use `ISNULL()` like this? Using such code in a `WHERE` or `SELECT` statement to convert null values to something else would force a full table scan. Using this in a `SELECT` statement isn't possible

Comment: @MarcGuillot But read [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/347996/converting-an-empty-string-0-int-does-not-honor-round-trip-conversion-undocumented) which says that casting an empty string to numeric results in error.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's also what I expected, but I have checked and select cast('' as integer) returns 0.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's an extremely old and *closed* documentation issue. It doesn't say that the cast is invalid, just that the documentation omits this.

Answer (score 2):

In this case `ISNULL(0,'')` returns an integer. SQL Server will cast the second argument to an integer too, ie 0. So 0=0, hence the result is TRUE. Comparing directly to 0 would also return true:

```
IF 0 = '' 
      select 'true' 

else 
     select 'false'
```

Using ISNULL and NULL like this is unusual. An `ISNULL(someColumn='')` function in a `WHERE` clause would prevent the optimizer from using any indexes that covered `someColumn` thus forcing a scan instead of an index seek.

Using IF statements in SELECT is impossible. Even in CASE statements, it's better to explicitly check for NULL than apply such transformations.

Comment: ok, thx for explanation.  i tried "select cast ('' as int)" and it returns 0

Comment: @Star why are you doing this anyway? What is the actual problem you want to solve by this `IF ISNULL` construct? Most likely, there are easier and faster ways to do it

Answer (score 2):

For your case, when compare two values, the `''` will be converted to `int` first.  The following:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, '')
```

returns `0`, so `0=0` is true

If you want treat 0 as `NULL`, you can use `NULLIF`:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0
IF NULLIF(ISNULL(@i, ''), 0) = ''
     SELECT 'true'
ELSE
     SELECT 'false'
```

This would return `'false'`

Answer (score 0):

ISNULL are identical when there are just two values (i.e. NULL and 0) so, it will be true in IF condition and select 'true' will be printed.